# Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) on iOS without CocoaPods

Tags: ios, github, google-cloud-messaging

Basically that,

I have been tasked to set this up without actually using CocoaPods. Problem is, everywhere on Google's documentation they insist to use this. I can't find the github project with GCM for iOS and figure out which files I need to drag into my xcode project.

Comment: I don't think you can use GCM without Cocoapods. See [Setting up a GCM Client App on iOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client?ver=objc). As of now I think this is not possible, as in the entire documentation only Cocoapods is the one available.

Comment: There is no GitHub project containing the GCM library for iOS. The cocoapod for GCM has many dependency cocoapods (each of which also has dependencies). You can look at the podspec for any cocoapod (e.g. you can search for cocoapods on the Cocoapods web site and it links to the podspec), and it will contain stuff like dependencies and the URL to download the file. However, I am not sure how difficult it would be to figure out how to take that apart yourself and make it work in your project without building it through Cocoapods.

Answer (score 2):

Now it it's possible to use it without cocoapods https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks
Integrate without CocoaPods

If you don't want to use Cocoapods you can still take advantage of the Firebase SDKs by importing the frameworks directly.

Download the framework SDK zip (this is a ~100MB file and may take some time).
Unzip and see the README file for which Frameworks to include in to your project.
Add the ObjC linker flag in your Other Linker Settings in your target's build settings.